# How to use a SASS variable to calculate a number?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following CSS code, which hides rows 8 and on:

```
table tr:nth-child(n+8) {
  display: none;
}
```

However, I would like numbers 8 to be calculated, since it might change.  Specifically, I'd like it be `6 + myOffset`

So in SASS, I am trying the following:

```
$myOffset: 2;

/* try 1 */
table tr:nth-child(n+6+$myOffset) {
  display: none;
}

/* try 2 */
table tr:nth-child(n+6+{$myOffset}) {
  display: none;
}

/* try 3 */
table tr:nth-child(n+6+#{$myOffset}) {
  display: none;
}
```

None of these seem to work.  Is this possible with SASS?

Comment: Have you tied interpolators? http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Comment: @Veehmot Yes.  Note `try 3` in my example.

Comment: You need to put the `+6` inside the interpolation, see my answer

Comment: @Veehmot Ahhh, thank you.  Didn't realize that calculations are happening inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation should work. Just add the `+6` inside the interpolation.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0exg59wq/) here.

```
$myOffset: 2;

table tr:nth-child(n+#{$myOffset+6}) {
  display: none;
}
```